# Entity Framework 7 Errors from Key, Collection, Reference definitions missing in ASP.NET Beta 8

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Problem**

I am having trouble with upgrading my beta7 application to beta8. I had problems with over 50 errors, but now have gotten it down just to EF7. It was recommended by stack overflow friends and users that I ask this question specifically.

**Entity Framework Error**

> Error  CS1061  'EntityTypeBuilder<Unit>' does not contain a definition for 'Collection' and no extension method 'Collection' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder<Unit>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   SampleProject.DNX 4.5.1

I get the same error for `Reference` as well.

I have the following code in my `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` method in my DbContext.cs file.

```
builder.Entity<Unit>(entity =>
 {
     entity.HasKey(unit => unit.UnitId);
     entity.Collection(unit => unit.UnitBins).InverseReference(bin =>  bin.BinUnit)
                    .ForeignKey(bin => bin.UnitId).Required(true);
     entity.Reference(u => u.RefUnitType).InverseReference().ForeignKey<Unit>      (u   => u.RefUnitTypeId).Required();
            });
```

The problem is that EntityBuilder does not seem to have definitions for `Collection` and `Reference`. This is about the second or third time this kind of logic has been refactored in EF it feels like and so I am very confused as to how to rewrite my logic above.

**Attempts:**

I tried the following things:

- I tried using intellisense in VS15, but nothing similar was found
- I have searched the EF7 issues GitHub page, but didn't see anything
- I also tried `dnu restore` just to be sure the upgrade didn't do something strange with my project.json lock.
- Using `entity.HasKey()` instead of `entity.Key()`, but have not found other methods comparable to the others?

Now that beta8 is feature complete, I may rewrite significant portions of my project. However, for now I need to resolve these errors so that I can compile the project again. Any help, assistance, and advice rendered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Collection => HasMany
Reference => HasOne
InverseReference => WithOne
```

Comment: If you can sir, can you please tell me how you learned of these refactored terms? I want to be more informed of the changes moving forward. :)

Comment: Subscribe to the [Announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) repo. The EF7 team posts breaking changes there.